# XSLT crashes when encountering Ampersand sign

Tags: ampersand

I am currently running in some trouble when trying to output a certain XML tag containing the Ampersand sign (&).

So more concrete, when I try to output the following tag. I get an error

```
<fullname>Ben & Jerry</fullname>
```

Using the following tag however runs just fine

```
<fullname>Ben and Jerry</fullname>
```

I have tried it with the following code

```
<xsl:template match="fullname">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

And I also tried

```
<xsl:template match="fullname">
    <xsl:value-of-select="." disable-output-escaping="Yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Both resulted in an error. The only way how I get it to work is by using CDATA like this

```
<fullname><![CDATA[Ben & Jerry]]></fullname>
```

However, I have no control over the XML files I receive, and as such this is not a viable option. Is there something I can do within the XSLT to circumvent/fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If it contains an unescaped &, it's **not** xml.  Tell whoever is supplying you with xml that they've failed.

Comment: Thanks Don Roby. However, I have no control over the outputted XML files. As such I am trying to find a workaround. Ideally while still containing the Ampersand in the data, but I would also be happy if the XSLT would just ignore the sign alltogether.

Comment: @Jaco: "no control" is a relative term. If you were asked to produce 100 equations in which two even numbers add up to an odd number, you'd say that's not possible: the requirements are in error. The same is true when you're asked to produce XML that's not XML. Similar considerations apply to input XML. I'm not trying to say you can't consider a workaround for erroneous input or erroneous requirements, but when I hear "I have no control" I always think, "That's not strictly true."

Comment: BTW: What errors did you see (the ones you mentioned above)? Also, what does the input XML look like (a sample)? I'm guessing there are ampersands in your input XML, which are escaped (whether by `&amp;` or by CDATA); but it's not clear.

Comment: "I would also be happy if the XSLT would just ignore the sign alltogether." So the requirement for your output is that ampersands can appear if they are unescaped, or they can be omitted, but they can't be serialized in the normal well-formed XML way? That sounds crazy for a requirement. Can you give us more detail about what the requirements are for the output XML, and why you can't just output the XML in the natural way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ampersand can't appear as itself in well-formed XML.  Your example should be

```
<fullname>Ben &amp; Jerry</fullname>
```

I don't think you'll be able to get around this with any XSLT processor.  You need to fix whatever generates the XML so it is well-formed.

Comment: I'm still wondering whether that example is meant to indicate input XML. The OP says "when I try to output the following tag". But I think you're assuming he's trying to copy it from an input quasi-XML document, and I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

> So more concrete, when I try to output the following tag. I get an
>   error
>
> `<fullname>Ben & Jerry</fullname>`

Actually, this isn't a tag. It's a start tag followed by some invalid content followed by an end tag.

You can't output invalid content using XSLT. If you have to output something that isn't XML, you'll need to use a non-XML tool to do it. And you're more likely to get advice on a non-XML forum.

What you haven't made clear is exactly what your input and output are. You say you are trying to output invalid XML, but you don't say what the input is.